# Create array from AJAX request data and use in another function

Tags: jquery, json

```js
$('#get_test').click(function(){
    $.post('ajax-request.php', {   
        act: 'start_test'
    }, function(data) { 
        var jstring = $.parseJSON(data);
```

So now in `jstring` I have data associated with `english_word` and `russian_word`. How could I save `russian_word` data in an array and use it in a different function?

Comment: can you post the data format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could either pass the data directly to the other function within your success handler function like so

```
$('#get_test').click(function(){
    $.post('ajax-request.php', {   
        act: 'start_test'
    }, function(data) { 
        var jstring = $.parseJSON(data);
        myFunction(jstring.russian);
```

or you could persist the data to a scoped variable :

```
var russian=[];
$('#get_test').click(function(){
    $.post('ajax-request.php', {   
        act: 'start_test'
    }, function(data) { 
        var jstring = $.parseJSON(data);
        russian=jstring.russian;
```

and then pick up the value in your function :

```
   function myFunc(){
     Console.log(russian);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! Scoped variable was what I need))

Answer (score 0):

declare a new array variable, and directly put the value from "jstring"  using dot operator.

$('#get_test').click(function(){
    $.post('ajax-request.php', {
        act: 'start_test'
    }, function(data) { 
        var jstring = $.parseJSON(data);

```
   var russian_word = new Array();
    russian_word = jstring.russian_word;
```

}

this will give you array of "russian_word".... i hope it would work for you...thanks